# How to handle data from multiple v-forms inside v-tabs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have created a v-card with the purpose of holding some v-tabs. Inside these v-tabs, I have a v-form. The forms correspond to the imports made, since each of them is a component. The goal of the forms is for the user to complete all the fields in each of them, which in the end will create the "question" which has to be sent to the database. This means that I need to connect all the information inside all the forms. At the moment I have something like this:

```
<v-card class="mt-2" elevation="10" >
  <v-tabs v-model="tab" centered show-arrows>
     <v-tab v-for="item in items" :key="item.tab">
         {{ item.tab }}
     </v-tab>
  </v-tabs>
  <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
     <v-tab-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.tab"> 
          <component v-bind:is="item.content"></component>
     </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs-items>
</v-card>

<script>
import Caracterizacao from '@/components/Caracterizacao';
import Pergunta from '@/components/Pergunta';
import Respostas from '@/components/Respostas';
import Suporte from '@/components/Suporte';
import Edicao from '@/components/Edicao';

export default {
  components: { 
        Caracterizacao, 
        Pergunta,
        Respostas,
        Suporte,
        Edicao
    }, 
  data() {
    return{
      tab: null,
      items: [
        { tab: 'Caracterizacão', content: 'Caracterizacao'},
        { tab: 'Pergunta', content: 'Pergunta'},
        { tab: 'Respostas', content: 'Respostas'},
        { tab: 'Suporte', content: 'Suporte'},
        { tab: 'Edição', content: 'Edicao'}
      ]
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

I saw an example where I could set $refs to each form when being created, but the forms were being hard coded, while I'm creating them dynamically. How can I get this done?

Comment: why not sum up all the forms in a parent component?

Comment: In such cases, we usually use emits or vuex. If you need such functionality only a few times using emits is fine, but after some point, it gets too complex.

Comment: @Deniz could you elaborate a bit more please? I've started working with vue and vuetify this week. Maybe you could show me an example with what you're saying?

Comment: @BülentAkgül Thanks, I'll look into each one and post the results here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i don't get you wrong now, you have two possible solutions.

1. you use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and hold all the form data in a single `store.state`
   then you have a single source of data which can be send to your backend.
   (highly recommended way)
2. use a parent component and [$emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) the data in each form till you got the wished data to send it to your backend from your very parent component.
   Here i made a example for you. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bhabha-8cvk6?)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into each one and post the results here later.

Comment: I think that for this, using the parent component and $emit should be good. Any chance you could give me an example of 2 forms, the parent component and how to handle the parent component on the code i posted above?

Comment: @JoãoAmorim can you just make me a CodeSandbox with two forms inside a simple component? then i will show you how to handle the data.

Comment: Yes, I will post it here as soon as i get back home!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-elion-hkxc7 Hopefully that's what you asked for.

Comment: @JoãoAmorim i added a CodeSandbox in my answer

Comment: Also, instead of sending data back to the parent by clicking a button, you may use a watcher in each tab and send the object back to the parent on each change.